# Basic SQL query design issue

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a query that would basically be the equivelant of this (does not work).

```
SELECT * FROM `categories` AS C AND
SELECT * FROM `items` AS I AND
SELECT COUNT(I.id) AS items AND
SELECT SUM(I.price) AS price;
```

I am not using SQLServer, and I'm using PDO through PHP for database connectivity.

Here's the tables.

**Category**

> ```
> +----+------------+
> | id |  Category  |
> +----+------------+
> |  1 | First_Cat  |
> |  2 | Second_Cat |
> +----+------------+
> ```

**items**

```
+----+----------+------+-------+
| id | category | name | price |
+----+----------+------+-------+
|  1 |        1 | Foo  | 1.99  |
|  2 |        1 | Bar  | 2.00  |
|  3 |        2 | ooF  | 0.99  |
|  4 |        2 | raB  | 1.99  |
+----+----------+------+-------+
```

Based on these tables I would be expecting these query results:

```
+----+------------+-------+-------+--+
| id |  category  | items | price |  |
+----+------------+-------+-------+--+
|  1 | First_Cat  |     2 | 3.99  |  |
|  2 | Second_Cat |     2 | 2.98  |  |
+----+------------+-------+-------+--+
```

Any help?

Comment: Does it work without PHP?

Comment: No, I'm trying to figure out the basic structure, but posted that I was using PHP as some people will give SQL server solutions.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Modified the question to be more clear

Comment: Show us what you've done with your PHP and we should be able to help. I don't think anyone will want to write the code from scratch for you.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - That's just the problem, it doesn't work correctly. It duplcated and smashes it all into a single category --- `SELECT C.*, COUNT(P.category) AS `items`, SUM(P.price) as `total` FROM `categories` C, `items` P`

Comment: Please edit your OP to make any changes, corrections or clarifications. Dumping code in comments makes them unreadable and your question is still not clear. What does any of this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Preferably you would try to do the work yourself and then post on SO when you run into specific problems that you can't solve by Googling, not, as Jay says, ask people to write the code from scratch for you.

Answer (score 2):

The query that you have posted in the comment you are not joining the category table and the item table. That makes me think that you could do something like this?:

```
SELECT 
    categories.id,
    categories.Category,
    COUNT(*) AS items,
    SUM(items.price) as price
FROM 
    `categories`
    JOIN items
        ON categories.id = items.category
GROUP BY
    categories.id,
    categories.Category
```

Comment: I've tried modifying this to get it to work; However I could not. The query should return the amount of items that have the `category` field set to the `id` field of the id. Which i see here, however I don't understand how COUNT(*) AS items would ever poll the items table? Getting a query error no-matter how I try it.

Comment: Thanks though, the JOIN keyword gave me the information that I needed to get this working.